# Cannot reconnect controller when it shuts off automatically - Payday 2 Crimewave Edition

Tags: xbox-one, payday-2

Sometimes, I'll pause my game to go do something and occasionally I'm away for so long that my controller turns off to save battery power. Like most games, a message pops up asking for you to reconnect your controller.  However, no matter how many times I press the `A` button to make the message go away, it refuses to do so.

I've tried pressing other buttons, going to the Xbox dashboard and resuming the game, disconnecting and reconnecting the controller again, but nothing works. I then have to reset my game, and lose any progress I've made.

Anyone else have this problem and know a way to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happened to me twice. But I think it may have been fixed with the update.
I changed my battery in between games and got the message to reconnect the controller which I did and it still worked.